# WebServiceTemplate soap ws using dynamic wsdl

Tags: java, spring, soap, dynamic, wsdl

I am trying to build a soap ws client using WebServiceTemplate but I use a dynamic wsdl and when i configure my bean:

```
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"
    p:marshaller-ref="jaxbMarshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="jaxbMarshaller"
    p:defaultUri="http://127.0.0.1:8080/com-example-gateway-store/endpoints"
    p:messageSender-ref="messageSender">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
</bean>
```

I get a null pointer exception because it can not find the endpoint for the wsdl or a 404 not found error.

We have 2 dynamically generated WSDLs exposed (using Spring features) this way:

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="x" portTypeName="X"
    locationUri="/endpoints/" requestSuffix="Request" responseSuffix="Response"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/gateway/store/x/schema/v1">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/classes/schemas/x.xsd" />
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="y" portTypeName="Y"
    locationUri="/endpoints/" requestSuffix="Request" responseSuffix="Response"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/gateway/store/y/schema/v1">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/classes/schemas/y.xsd" />
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

Any help ?